# expression must be a modifiable lvalue with 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

In this code (C++) , I try to move forward the pointer which point on one "row" of 2D array, to the next row, vice verca with the next row. so I've tried this code:

```
void bubleSort(char mat[][WORDS]) {
    for (int i = LETTERS; i >= 0; i--) {
        int position = 0;                                           //This variable is used to move forward in case of same previous letters
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            if (mat[j][position] < mat[j - 1][position]) {          //If the words are not sorted according to alphabetic order,
                mat[j]--;                                           //swap the poniters of the rows of their letters positions,
                mat[j - 1]++;
                position = 0;                                       //and initilize 'position' for the next words check.
            }
            else if (mat[j][position] == mat[j - 1][position]) {    //If current position of letter have the same letters,
                position++;                                         //jump to next position,
                j = ((position < LETTERS - 1) ? j - 1 : i);         //and move 'j' back to recheck the words.
            }
            else position = 0;                                      //if thoose words stay in their place, initilize 'position' for next checking
        }
    }
}
```

Then the compiler says "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" about these rows:

```
mat[j]--;                                           //swap the poniters of the rows of their letters positions,
mat[j - 1]++;
```

How should I fix it?

thanks.

Comment: You cannot increment arrays, because arrays are not pointers.

Comment: With `std::vector<std::string> v;`, you may just do `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Comment: BTW, you may use `std::swap(mat[j], mat[j - 1])`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `char array[][N]` means that you are using a flat 2D array, all the data are laid sequentially in one location. The 2nd row is right after the 1st in memory, and the index is actually calculated as x*N+y (for array[x][y]). Therefore there is no pointer for each row. You need to define an array of pointers and populate it if you want to directly swap rows instead of copying them.

Also, incrementing a 'row', will probably never be what you want, because the pointer will just points to the next element in the same row. You need to actually swap the pointers (you can use `std::swap`) to swap the rows.